# Overriding theme_item_list in a context

Tags: 7, theming

I am using [Views Tree](https://drupal.org/project/views_tree) plugin to render a taxonomy. I need to get rid of the surrounding `<div class="item-list"></div>` wrappers. While I could simply override the theme_item_list function in my template, I would like the override to only take place within a view. Otherwise the wrapper is just fine. What kind of 'if' should I use around it to apply a Views context?

Answer (score 1):

You can to get rid of the surrounding  wrappers by overriding theme_item_list($variables) function in you template.php or module and comment hardcoded lines:

```
    $output = '<div class="item-list">';
```

and

```
    $output = '</div>';
```

See details on http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify the settings in the view itself, so that the wrapper class is not included.  Since you're using Drupal 7, just click on the '**Settings**' link next to the '**HTML list**' in the Format section (as in my screenshot) and then remove or modify the wrapper class it usually uses by default.

Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: Thanks Boriana, but this hold true if you're using HTML list. I'm using a different style plugin, which processes its output list through theme_item_list.

Comment: Sorry about that!  I didn't gather that from your original question, though I should have.  This is very interesting, so I'm wondering if you ever solved your issue...

Answer (score 0):

Since the views tree module doesn't provide a specific hook when it calls theme('item_list') it means you cannot specifically target it's lists easily.

For more information on specific hooks see the $hook parameter docs for the [theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) function.

(I created a [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2396327) for this)

This means you have to [override](https://www.drupal.org/node/55126) theme_views_tree_inner() to override the call to theme('item_list']) then override [theme_item_list()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7).

You could do it by adding these theme functions to your template.php of your theme (I'm assuming you are using views tree 7.x-2.0):

```
/**
 * Inner recursive theme function for views tree theming.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 * @param $view
 * @param $options
 * @param $row
 * @param $title
 * @param $result
 *   An array representing the raw data returned from the query.
 * @param $parent
 *   The id of the parent entry in the call stack.
 */
function THEMENAME_views_tree_inner($variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $options = $variables['options'];
  $rows = $variables['rows'];
  $title = $variables['title'];
  $result = $variables['result'];
  $parent = $variables['parent'];

  $items = array();
  foreach ($result as $i => $record) {
    if ($record->views_tree_parent == $parent) {
      $variables['parent'] = $record->views_tree_main;
      $items[] = $rows[$i] . call_user_func(__FUNCTION__, $variables);
    }
  }

  // Override call to theme('item_list']) with a call to
  // theme('item_list__views_tree') so we can easily theme views
  // tree lists specifically.
  return count($items) ? theme('item_list__views_tree', array('items' => $items, 'type' => $options['type'])) : '';
}
```

Then override theme_item_list but name the function like this to user your more specific hook:

```
/**
 * Returns HTML for a list or nested list of items for the views tree module.
 */
function THEMENAME_item_list__views_tree($variables) {

}
```